# how to make my route to work with my controller in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an API with  NodeJS and express

When ever i visit a route, it will work if its not connected with my controller like for example

```
router.get("/get", (req, res) => res.send({"data":"Its works"}));
```

But when ever i add the controller, it will take forever for that route to respond

```
const controllers = require('./controllers');
router.get("/get", (req, res) => controllers.findAll);
```

Here is the controller code

```
const findAll = async (req, res) => {
    res.send({ error: "error.message" })
}
module.exports = { findAll }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is never executed. Change it to pass the controller function instead:

```
const controllers = require('./controllers');
router.get("/get", controllers.findAll);
```